# How to properly set InputType for EditText?

Tags: android, input, numbers

I want my *EditText* content type as numeric. I set *InputType* which is **2** according to the [reference](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/InputType.html#TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER). But it's still possible to input any character.

```
final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

What am I doing wrong here?

*I can't use XML, but I have EditTextPreference with `android:inputType="number"` and it works properly.*

**EDIT:**

Here is some more code:

```
case R.id.set_counter:
AlertDialog.Builder setCounterDialog = new AlertDialog.Builder(this);
setCounterDialog.setTitle("Set counter value");

final EditText input = new EditText(this);
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
InputFilter[] filter = new InputFilter[1];
filter[0] = new InputFilter.LengthFilter(4);
input.setFilters(filter);

setCounterDialog.setView(input);
setCounterDialog.setPositiveButton("Ok", new OnClickListener() {
    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
        String inputText = input.getText().toString();
        counter = Integer.parseInt(inputText);
        counterLabel = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.counter);
        counterLabel.setText(inputText);
    }
});
setCounterDialog.setNegativeButton("Cancel", null);
setCounterDialog.show();
return true;
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

use just input type instead

`input.setInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);`

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
InputType.TYPE_CLASS_PHONE
```

Answer (score 1):

First call with null, then call with input type number:

```
input.setRawInputType(null);
input.setRawInputType(InputType.TYPE_CLASS_NUMBER);
```

Comment: how it will take null as argument as it is taking int as argument which is promitive type.